# Server-to-Server app install tracking -- shows up in Analytics and App Events Tester

Tags: facebook

Am using the "ping-back server endpoint" as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-conversions-endpoint/v2.4 to manually log app installs and events from our server to Facebook's.

These events show up in facebook app analytics (with Platform Unknown), but, on the App Ads Helper, I still see Last iOS Install Unavailable.
I assume this is because the iOS sdk (which we are not using) sends something in the headers that our server does not?

Is there a parameter that we can use to make the server-to-server MOBILE_APP_INSTALL events work for ad conversion tracking?

Thanks

example request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'event=MOBILE_APP_INSTALL&advertiser_id=A4787B8B-2951-45F0-807C-A6AF5A445702&application_tracking_enabled=1&advertiser_tracking_enabled=1' 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/758041614305509/activities'
```

Would attach screenshots if I was allowed...

Comment: Cannot see anything wrong in your request. Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: @folizc No, we resolved it by faking the user-agent in the request. Pretending to be safari on iPad fixed it, but it sure feels like a hack.